# "Include" extension method does not work with LinqKit

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6, linqkit

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Remuneration
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Employee Employee {get;set;}
    public int Amount {get;set;}
}
```

The normal query:

```
return _context.Remunerations.Include("Employee")
```

works perfect

But when I am using Albahari's LinqKit and giving the query as below:

```
return _context.Remunerations.AsExpandable().Include("Employee")
```

It does not give any error there.

**But does not include the Employee data in the result**.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/issues/14) and they're working on it. The current [development source](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/blob/master/src/ExpandableQuery.cs) has an extension method that executes `Include` on an `ExpandableQuery` (returned by `AsExpandable()`) and delegates it back to the original `IQueryable`.

The reason why you don't get an exception is that `Include` is an extension method on `IQueryable<T>`, and `ExpandableQuery` also implements `IQueryable`. But it doesn't have an implementation of `Include()`, so `Include()` runs, but it does nothing.